# Is it safe to set file sync level 0 in aeron cluster in production?

Tags: aeron

I know it's unsafe to set file sync level 0 in a single node aeron cluster, because, in case of a crash, some data can be lost.

But what if we have at least 5 nodes in the cluster? I guess it is quite rare for 3 nodes to crash simultaneously! (if just 1 or 2 nodes crashes, all other nodes can still operate normally.)

Currently, what is the actual file sync level on the financial aeron clusters in production?

Answer (score 4):

There is no simple answer to this question. It is a matter of understanding the risks taken with any approach and judging if this is acceptable for the business case. Things to consider include a software bug that may terminate all nodes deterministically, or data centre power failure. Very few financial organisations are willing to share their internal decisions.

Comment: thanks, I'm testing using raid controller with BBU and Intel SSD with "power loss protection" feature. Setting up a 3 node cluster and randomly powering off some or all nodes. It seems setting sync level 0 is safe.

Comment: Disabling os page cache & setting sync level 2 with this hardwares is also good option.